# Sorting several arrays according to one array

Tags: swift

How can I sort a bunch of arrays according to the array `createdAt` (ex. "2015-11-02 19:19:35 +0000")? And is it beneficial to combine them into another type (Dictionary?) for use in a tableView, if so how?

```
var comment = [AnyObject]()
var createdAt = [AnyObject]()
var paid = [AnyObject]()
var startedAt = [AnyObject]()
var state = [AnyObject]()
var stripeId = [AnyObject]()
var type = [AnyObject]()
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you !

Comment: there is some relation between you arrays? if i understand your request, all arrays have the same amount of items and you are modeling one record of data as items from all arrays with the same index. i suggest you create a struct with comment, paid, createdAt ... and make the array of this struct.

Comment: Exactly, how please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct Data {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var gender: Bool
}
let r1 = Data(id: 10,name: "alfa", gender: true)
let r2 = Data(id: 8,name: "beta", gender: true)
let r3 = Data(id: 12,name: "gama", gender: false)

var arr: Array<Data> = []
arr.append(r1)
arr.append(r2)
arr.append(r3)

print(arr)
arr.sortInPlace { (data1, data2) -> Bool in
    data1.id < data2.id
}
print(arr)
```

like this ...

Comment: Actually I don't understand how your comment to mye question relates to you answer.  I have dateArray = [NSDate, NSDate, NSDate] and commentArray = [String, String, String] and paidArray = [Bool, Bool, Bool].  First how do I get them into a Struct like you have shown where r1 = Data(date:NSDate, comment: String, paid: Bool) ?

Answer (score 0):

Are each of these arrays related to the createdAt array? So for instance, item 1 in createdAt has a value in paid array at item 1? If so it might be better to create a class to hold your comment, createdAt, paid, etc and then create one array with all the items in. Then you can easily sort this.